# SQL Server dateformat questionable behavior

Tags: sql-server

Put this piece of code in query analyzer and hit F5.

```
declare @aaa datetime
set @aaa='01/12/2011'
set dateformat dmy
select month(@aaa)
```

It gives you 1. Hit F5 again, it gives you 12. Why?

Comment: Query Analyzer? Have I been time-warped back 10 years?

Comment: If you use a **language-/location-independent** string-based date (e.g. the **ISO-8601** standard format `YYYYMMDD`) - e.g. `set @aaa = '20111201'` - then you can switch around between date formats as many times as you like - you'll **ALWAYS** get `12` for the month ......

Answer (score 1):

This is because your line `set dateformat dmy` is half way through the script.

This is switching your date format after the initial assignment for the first 'F5' but then this is persisted for the second 'F5'

If you make it the first line it should be consistent and return 12 each time

To be clear - the `set dateformat dmy` makes a difference for the `set @aaa='01/12/2011'` line as it affects the way that the string `'01/12/2011'` is parsed to a datetime.

On the first run, the @aaa will actually contain the date '12-Jan-2011', whereas after you `set dateformat dmy` it will contain the date '01-Dec-2011'.

Comment: set dateformat dmy it has to be there. @aaa is just a parmeter received by the stored procedure. The first 2 lines is to try the procedure at design time

Comment: @Florin: That wasn't stated in the question - the more information you give, the better an answer you get. Where is the stored proc called from?

Comment: OK. Sorry. Let's see. You have this procedure: CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]
 @dDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 set dateformat dmy
 select month(@dDate)

END
 If you execute the procedure it return 1 instead of 12

Comment: @Florin: That still doesn't state where the proc is called from. Are you calling from sql code, or from elsewhere (eg .net)

Comment: from .net. It's an parameter of type 'dd/mm/yyyy'

Comment: `'dd/mm/yyyy'` is not a type.

Comment: I presume its a string in that format. You need to parse it into a datetime .net variable and pass that to the proc.

Comment: @Florin. Please will you review your question and compare it to the actual scenario. Then add anything you think might be useful to actually answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because the first time you ran the code, the date was stored internally as January 12th. The set setting sticks to your session, then you ran it again so you redeclared the variable, and this time it was interpreted as December 1st. The set setting doesn't affect datepart functions like `MONTH()` because the date has already been interpreted and isn't stored internally the way you've typed it.

Instead of declaring date literals with regional and ambiguous formatting, you should always use safe, unambiguous formats. For datetime/smalldatetime:

```
yyyymmdd
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss
```

For date:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

If you want to display dates in these friendly but confusing formats, by all means do that at the presentation layer. But don't try to confuse SQL Server with them. Please read [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) and [this article by Tibor Karaszi](http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes).